# Authorization from model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a `Board.php` model with a method `checkViewAccess()`

i.e

```
@if($board->checkViewAccess())
    render board
@endif
```

It does a few checks, and on the last check it needs to call a policy method to determine authorization for the user.

- In blade, `@can('view', $board)` works
- In controllers, `$this->authorize('view', $board)` works

But I cannot for the life of me find out any way to call a policy authorization from the `Board` model

What I've tried:

- `Gate::check('view', $this)` // Non-static method, which is fine, didn't expect it to work
- `auth()->user()->can('view', $this)` // This doesn't even hit the policy and returns false regardless of what I return from the policy. Even if I just return true in the `before()` policy method it's false. Laravel docs claim the `can()` method is avaiable on the user object
- `$user->can('view', $this);` // Thinking it was an issue with the auth facade, I fetched the user directly from the database and it still didn't hit the policy

So how can I achieve this? How can I access laravels authorization from a model?

Comment: A question you need to ask yourself is "why do I need this in the model?" and then "is there a better place I could put it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the `Laratrust` package which uses the `can()` method in a trait, so I can't add my own Authorizable trait to my user model

Fix:

```
use LaratrustUserTrait;
use Authorizable {
    LaratrustUserTrait::can insteadof Authorizable;
    Authorizable::can as authorize;
}
```

Comment: If you have solved your issues you may want to accept your own answer ;)

Comment: Have to wait a few days before it allows me